# Android Image Base Size

Tags: android

I am building some graphics for an Android application and plan on making each image several times to fit the different DPI categorys such as ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and so on.

I am aware of the sizes each image needs for example, an MDPI image of 48x48 would be 72x72 HDPI 96x96 XHDPI ect. My question is, how do you know what size to make the base image (MDPI), say i am making a button for my home screen, how would i know the base dimensions that button needs to fit in the MDPI category and from there i can adjust it to the other categorys.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at design at X, here is a good artcile [Designing at 1x](https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/designing-at-1x-33240842180c#.oruk584b3)